How to avoid multiplying rows
I want to create measure base on information from two separate tables.

Logic of measure is:
IF "RM Valuation classes" (form PLANT) is equal to "RM"
THEN return "Raw material class" (from VALUATION_CLASS) -> if this is empty then "N"
IF "RM Valuation classes" (form PLANT) is not equal to "RM" then "Y"
I've created measure
Raw material valuation class Y/N = 
VAr RM_val = MAXX(Plant,Plant[RM Valuation classes])
VAR Val_class = MAXX(Material,Material[Valuation Class])
Return
IF(RM_val="RM",IFERROR(CALCULATE(MAXX(Valuation_class,Valuation_class[Raw material class]),Valuation_class[Valuation Class]=Val_class),"N"),"Y")

In general measure is working if I have simple table



Material NO
Raw material valuation class Y/N




Material 1
Y


Material 2
N



Although, if I add "Valuation class" from VALUATION_CLASS then rows are multiply by all possible combinations of "Valuation class".
Without measure I receive of course correct table of Material NO and Valuation Class.
How I should adjust measure to have correct view of table?

In Material tab there are plenty Material and each have Valuation class.
Valuation_class tab includes unique  "valuation classes"

Setting "Cross Filter direction" to "Both" doesn't help.

Thanks. I'll check other options later.
